# best way to convert a complete spark dataframe to list

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using df.collect to get the complete list , but performance wise its very slow. can anyone suggest a better way to convert a complete df to list and not just a single column.

Comment: why do you need a list from a dataframe??

Comment: i want to do something like this. i have a `df` and a `list` with different column names. so i am trying to create a query where `list.column1> df.value1 and list.column1 < df.value1 AND list.column2> df.value2 and list.column2 < df.value2 `AND ...... so on.. how can i achieve the same if i don't convert the df to a list?